# How can I use the Heun's method to solve this first order Initial Value Problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

**My Problem** is this given Initial Value Problem: $$y^{\prime}=\frac{3x-2y}{x}\quad y(1)=0$$ I am looking for a way to solve this problem using [Heun's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heun%27s_method). I have a given Interval of $[1,2]$ and a given step size of $h=0.1$

The example is already solved with a numerical solution. But i want to know more. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439205/how-can-i-solve-this-initial-value-problem-using-the-euler-method). After discussing the solution by Eulers Method with a friend, he told me about Heun's method. But we failed to apply it to our example. How would Heun's method be applied to this problem?

Comment: I know you are not looking for this. But have you tried the integration factor method? To me it looks fine, although the solution is not explicit: it involves an integral.

Comment: When i am finished, i will try this method as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are given:

$$y'=\dfrac{3x-2y}{x}\quad y(1)=0$$

Interval is $x \in[1,2]$, and a given step size $h=0.1$

For Heun's (Improved Euler's), we have:

- $h = \dfrac{b-a}{N} = .1 = \dfrac{2-1}{N} \rightarrow N = 10$
- $x = a = 1, y(a) = y(1) = \alpha = 0 \rightarrow a = 1, \alpha = 0$
- Set: $x_0 = 1, x_i = 1 + 0.1 i, y_0 = 0$
- Using Heun's (Improved Euler's), we have:

$y_{i+1} = y_{i} + \dfrac{h}{4}\left[f(x_i, y_i)+3f(x_i + \dfrac{2}{3}h, y_i+\dfrac{2}{3}hf(x_i,y_i))\right]$, so

$y_{i+1} = y_{i} + \dfrac{1}{40}\left[\dfrac{3 x_{i-1} - 2 y_{i-1}}{x_{i-1}} + 3\left(\dfrac{3 (x_i + \dfrac{2}{3}(.1)) - 2 (y_i+\dfrac{2}{3}(.1)\dfrac{3 x_{i-1} - 2 y_{i-1}}{x_{i-1}}}{x_i + \dfrac{2}{3}(.1)}\right)    \right]$

- For $i= 1$, we have:

$x_0 = 1, y_0 = 0, y_1 = 0 + \dfrac{1}{40}\left[3 + 3\dfrac{3(1+(2/3)(.1)) - 2(2(.1))}{1 + (2/3)(.1)} \right]  = 0.271875$

Continuing this way, we generate the table:

$~~~~~\text{Step} ~~|~~ x ~~~|~~ y $

- $~~00 ~~|  1.0  ~~| ~~ 0.00000 $
- $~~01 ~~|  1.1 ~~| ~~ 0.271875 $
- $~~02 ~~|  1.2 ~~| ~~ 0.503084 $
- $~~03 ~~|  1.3 ~~| ~~ 0.705482 $
- $~~04 ~~|  1.4 ~~| ~~ 0.886908 $
- $~~05 ~~|  1.5 ~~| ~~ 1.05271 $
- $~~06 ~~|  1.6 ~~| ~~ 1.20664 $
- $~~07 ~~|  1.7 ~~| ~~ 1.35138 $
- $~~08 ~~|  1.8 ~~| ~~ 1.48891 $
- $~~09 ~~|  1.9 ~~| ~~ 1.6207 $
- $~~10 ~~|  2.0 ~~| ~~ 1.74786$

The exact solution is given by:

$$y(x) =  \dfrac{x^3-1}{x^2}$$

At $x=2$, we have: $y(2) = \dfrac{7}{4} = 1.75$

Compare that to Heun's (Improved Euler's) method, which has $1.74786$.

Look at how much better this estimate is over regular Euler's from earlier.

Comment: +1 very nice Amzoti. I don't know this method, but I think I need knowing it. :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend, those take me too long to type up! :-) Have a great day! Regards

Comment: Nice work, and + too for all the typing! (+)

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, it is good to do some of those once in a while to stay in practice! :-)

Comment: Whoa, that's a long hike! Were you "off" of work today? Or on an extended vacation (a couple days off tacked on the the long weekend?)

Comment: @amWhy: We are having our Summer weather - so I took this entire week off. Maybe Balboa park or Sea Port Village tomorrow (USS midway tour).